# Insert json to Mongodb from php7

Tags: php, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-7

I'm working on a migration project from php5.6 to 7.x in which I have a json with special characters in keys. How can I insert this to mongodb?

In php5.6 I was using MongoClient as the driver which internally converts the special characters and hence I was able to insert the document. But I'm not able to achieve the same in php7. I'm using MongoDB\Driver\Manager to connect to Mongodb.

EDIT:

I have a set of api's coming from another system with the below format

```
$content_array=
{
    "context": {
        "extensions": {
            "http://id.tincanapi.com/extension/platform": "web",
            "http://id.tincanapi.com/extension/browser-info": "Mozilla/5.0",
            "http://id.tincanapi.com/extension/host-session-id": "4e320015"
        }
    }
}
$dbconnection = new MongoDB\Client($uri);
$db = $dbconnection->$dbname;
$collection = $db->$dbcoll;

$collection->insertOne(json_decode($content_array));
```

It fails in the above , saying "Invalid document for insert: keys cannot contain \".\":in the key". 
I understand its a not a good practice to use these characters in the key, however since this piece of code works in php5.6 using MongoClient I wanted to keep the changes as minimal as possible when migrating to php7.

EDIT 2:

The piece of code which works in php5.6

```
$dbconnection = new \MongoClient($dbhost, $options); 
if (!empty($dbconnection)) {
$db = $dbconnection->selectDB($dbname);
$collection = $db->selectCollection($dbcoll);
$status = 0;
if (!empty($collection)) {
$collection->insert(json_decode($content_array));
$status = 1;
}
```

EDIT3:

part of me was wrong in not giving all details at once.. i do a json_decode to convert to native php array before inserting to mongo.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not using `MongoClient` now? You seem to be another victim of the poorly documented driver installation process. It's in "two" parts. The second part is here:[MongoDB PHP Library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/)

Comment: ok.. thank you.. let me try that

Comment: After using MongoDB\Client I'm still not able to insert a document in the above format. It still says Invalid document for insert: keys cannot contain \".\": .....

Comment: And your code is? Because I don't see any code here and I'm not sitting at your desk. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50790743/edit) and actually show what you are doing and where it does not work. Personally, I think it's a very bad idea to use these as "key" names, and you instead really should translate this into arrays of objects as `{ "url": ..., "value": ... }`

Comment: Edited.. I understand its a not a good practice to use these characters in the key, however since this piece of code works in php5.6 using MongoClient I wanted to keep the changes as minimal as possible when migrating to php7.

Comment: it's not a matter of "good practice" and MongoDB has no such constraint at all, which is why you were prompted to show it. But your edit is not even valid PHP code. Please show your real code that actually runs without an error.

Comment: I have edited the question itself. Please have a look.

Comment: You have not made the one change that matters. JSON is NOT PHP Code. This is the error you keep getting. Do you now understand? This `$content_array= "context" : {` is invalid.

Comment: no its not. Sorry for the copy-paste error and not giving full details at once.. However, I am getting a valid json and getting it inserted to mongodb with the above edited code.. there are no more changes in that.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize: although various versions of server will insert documents with such field names, the restriction on such field names was not lifted until 3.6 (according to the manual). Despite this change to the manual, MongoDB drivers officially do not support inserting such field names, and likely will not until some future version of the server implements an escaping scheme (SERVER-30575).

The reason you did not encounter that error in older versions of the PHP driver is that libmongoc did not start enforcing the restriction until 1.6.0 (CDRIVER-1341). PHP driver 1.2.x was still using libmongoc 1.5.x. This exception would have first appeared in PHP driver 1.3.x when we bumped to libmongoc 1.8.x.